If mouse over for more than x secons show popup
I am trying to implement a functionality where on moiseover event, I call a lightning modal component. But I want add 2 sec wait time atleast before the modal popup shows up.
HTML:
<span class="slds-text-heading_small slds-text-align_left">
   {name}
   &nbsp;
   <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:info" alternative-text="More Information" size="xx-small" id={someId} onmouseover={handleShowDetails}></lightning-icon>
</span>

JS:
handleShowDetails(event){
    //doing some logic execution
    //calling js method containing LWC Modal component
    this.callModal('Showing Details');
}

I have tried to wrap the callModal method call with setTimeout but not able to work it out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263636/if-mouse-over-for-over-2-seconds-then-show-else-dont

So, not to block the execution of your code's component, what you are looking for would be to have some state variables in your component to track whether or not the counter is up and counting, or not.
When user hovers over a certain part of the component, you trigger a function on that hover event that sets the counter. I think this function can run every time the mouse moves over the area you want it to hover, so I'd check if the counter is set before setting it up over and over again.
Then you need to do the opposite for when the mouse hovers out of the area you are dealing with. If the mouse stops hovering the area, then cancel the counter.
You are in the right track using setTimeout. But you need to bind the current component's context to call things, I believe. Then in this context you do the same thing as above: when the setTimeout function runs, you should check if the hovering is still happening (check the control variable) and then execute your code to open the modal (or not).
Should probably be something along the lines of this (this is pseudo-code, don't just copy and paste it):
onHover() {
  if (isHovering) return;
  isHovering = true;
  setTimer()
}

onHoverOut() {
  if (isHovering) isHovering = false;
}

setTimer() {
  // call setTimeout with the function that you want to run
  // for example "openModal"
}

openModal() {
  if (!isHovering) return;
  // run the code otherwise
}


thanks @renato for nice explaination.
JS:
timer;
modalcalled = false;
handleShowDetails(event){
if(!this.modalcalled){
this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
this.callModal('Show Details')
this.modalcalled = true;
} ,2000);
}
}
handleClearTimer(){
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
}

async callModal(title) {
    const result = await detailsModal.open({
    });
    if(result == undefined || result == Close){
        this.modalcalled = false;
    }
}

